# Extract a specific sequence of integers from a string Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to extract a specific sequence of integers from a string in Java

So I want to extract `239` from String 1, and `889` from String 2. I searched but what I found was to use regex and delete all non-digits. But I can't use that here because I don't want the `"1"` in `"Name1"`

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
                String s;
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/i1234/Desktop/Workspace/Assign4/src/input1.txt"));
                while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
                    s = s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
        }catch(IOException e){ //Exceptions handling
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try{
                if (br != null){
                    br.close();
                } 
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The input file is:

```
Name1 string 239

Name2 is a string 889

Word 432
```

The output is :

```
1239

2889

432
```

Comment: Would you mind posting what you've already produced?

Comment: Ok I used this code: import java.io.*;
public class Test1 {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  BufferedReader br = null;
  try{
    String s;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/i1234/Desktop/Workspace/Assign4/src/input1.txt"));
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
     s = s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
     System.out.println(s);
    }
  }catch(IOException e){ //Exceptions handling
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   try{
    if (br != null){
     br.close();
    } 
   }catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}
@YassinHajaj

Comment: the input1.txt file was:
Name1 is 239
Name 2 is 889
The output is: 1239
2889

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting the code in comments.

Comment: Please help now @YassinHajaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the lines in your file follow the same pattern, the following will do.

```
while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
    s = s.split(" ")[s.split(" ").length - 1];
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Please look at input again @Yassin Hajaj

Comment: @user3904375 Here it is.

Answer (score 1):

If there's something after the number you could use regex word boundarys:

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b").matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```